# Change values of dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, boolean

I create a dictionary (`Dictionary<string, bool> values`).

I create the function:

```
    private Dictionary<string, bool> ChangeValues(int line, Dictionary<string, bool> values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        {

        }

        return values;
    }
```

I want to change bool values according the number of line.

The table below is the result of a dictionary (only show the bool):

```
line 0 =  values["A"][false]
          values["B"][false]
          values["C"][false]

line 1 =  values["A"][false]
          values["B"][false]
          values["C"][true]

line 2 =  values["A"][false]
          values["B"][true]
          values["C"][false]

line n...
```

How I can change the bool value according the number of line?

Thanks.

**[update]**

After some help, the function is done:

```
    private Dictionary<string, bool> ChangeValues(int line, Dictionary<string, bool> values)
    {
        string[] keys = values.Keys.ToArray();

        keys = (from k in keys orderby k descending select k).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0, bit = 1; j < values.Count; j++, bit <<= 1)
            {
                values[keys[j]] = (i & bit) != 0;
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
```

Thanks to PeterDuniho

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input and the desired output? And what is the current output?

Comment: @FirstStep If the line is 0 all the boolean values will be false, If the line is 1 the last will be true, if the line is 2 the last but one will be true... Maybe is equal a binary logic?! I dont know...

Comment: And what do you mean by "_line is 0_"? You mean it is `= "0"` or what?

Comment: @FirstStep Basically if the dictionary have 3 inputs (A, B and C) the number max of lines will be 2^3 = 8 lines, if have 5 (A, B, C, D and E) 2^5 = 32 lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all you want is to be able to iterate all possible combinations of the flags stored in your dictionary. In addition, these flags correspond exactly to the bits in your loop variable `i`.

If so, then you can just use the bits from the loop variable directly to set the flag values in the dictionary. For a general solution, you do need to pass the key names as well, in the correct order according to the bits you want to set.

For example:

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> ChangeValues(int line, Dictionary<string, bool> values, string[] keys)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0, bit = 1; j < keys.Length; j++, bit <<= 1)
        {
            values[keys[j]] = (i & bit) != 0;
        }

        // do something with values here
    }

    return values;
}
```

Call like this:

```
var result = ChangeValues(8, values, new [] { "C", "B", "A" });
```

Note that the above simply modifies the dictionary that was passed in. I infer from the way the question was asked — *"I want to change bool values"* — that this was your intent. However, if you actually want to return a whole new dictionary object, you can do so:

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> ChangeValues(int line, string[] keys)
{
    Dictionary<string, bool> values = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0, bit = 1; j < keys.Length; j++, bit <<= 1)
        {
            values[keys[j]] = (i & bit) != 0;
        }

        // do something with values here
    }

    return values;
}
```

Of course, in that case the values of the original dictionary are of no use, so there's no need to pass it in, so I've left it out of the parameter list for this version of the method.

If in fact you want to return a new dictionary but still need the old one for some reason (e.g. you want to do something with it, like copying values or something, which you failed to mention in your question), then you can combine the two examples above to suit your needs.

Comment: It is hard to know what the asker wants, but it appears to me that your code overwrites the same entries in the `Dictionary<,>` over and over again? Am I wrong?

Comment: @Jeppe: you are correct; that's how I interpreted the question, which reads _"I want to change bool values"_, as opposed to _"I want to set bool values"_. It would be easy enough for the OP to create a new dictionary in the method if they want; but it's impossible for me to know whether they want that, or just wrote the method as a sort of "pseudo-fluent" syntax (i.e. returning the dictionary passed in).

Comment: So with your call example, `ChangeValues(8, values, new [] { "C", "B", "A" })`, when the outer loop variable `i` has been `0`, the `Dictionary<,>.Values` is FFF (three 'false'), then when `i` has been `1`, all of those are overwritten, and no we have FFT. In the end, it is just like we only ever had the ___last___ iteration of the outer loop variable `i`. So we always end up with stuff corresponding to `line - 1` in binary.

Comment: @Jeppe: yes. It's my assumption (though I should have included a comment) that the OP will actually _do_ something with the dictionary at each iteration. I admit, I'm still trying to figure out what the OP really wants. I know the basic technique he needs to use, but the rest of the context is very unclear. He put his loop _inside_ the method, so I did too. Just trying to be as close to his original example as possible. Looks like I managed to get close enough. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you very much, works beautifully :)

Comment: For the record, I also updated an existing `Dictionary<,>` passed in, in my "solutions" in my answer, so that was not what I meant. After you inserted `// do something` comments your code makes a bit sense. Still a bit strange to return the "last" dictionary in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, bool> ChangeValues(int line, Dictionary<string, bool> values)
{
  switch (line)
  {
    case 0:
      values["A"] = false;
      values["B"] = false;
      values["C"] = false;
      break;

    case 1:
      values["A"] = false;
      values["B"] = false;
      values["C"] = true;
      break;

    case 2:
      values["A"] = false;
      values["B"] = true;
      values["C"] = false;
      break;
  }

  return values;
}
```

Note: You can also have `void` return type (as in `static void ChangeValues`) and omit the `return values;` statement since you always return the same instance anyway, but that depends on whether you want a "fluent syntax" or not.

---

After comments, try this:

```
static Dictionary<string, bool> ChangeValues(int line, Dictionary<string, bool> values)
{
  var binary = Convert.ToString(line, 2);

  var key = 'A';
  foreach (var c in binary)
  {
    values[key.ToString()] = c == '1';
    key++;
  }

  return values;
}
```

The comment about `void` is the same as before.

Comment: The idea is correct, but if the dictionary have 5 inputs (A, B, C, D and E) ? The inputs are variables.

Comment: @jsfelipearaujo You want a binary representation?

Comment: I think yes, but how I can do this with a variable dictionary?